# Create a list of n distinct sets

Tags: python, python-2.7

P/S:This is not duplicate, I already have an answer myself which map to the answer in the duplicated solution, what I need is the shortest expression that is possible.

```
l=[set()]*passwordLen
l[0].add(1)
print l
```

will give result

```
[set([1]), set([1]), set([1]), set([1]), set([1]), set([1])]
```

but I need

```
[set([1]), set(), set(), set(), set(), set()]
```

what is the shortest expression to create list of sets that could achieve this?

what I could think of is

```
l=[set() for _ in xrange(passwordLen)]
l[0].add(1)
print l
```

Comment: So... what is the problem with what you already have?

Comment: @jonrsharpe possibility of a shorter expression than `l=[set() for _ in xrange(passwordLen)]`

Comment: You could make it one line with `l = [set() if x else set([1]) for x in xrange(passwordLen)]`, but really I suggest you just stick with what you have (which is simple and readable) and don't waste time trying to golf it.

Comment: Could you tell us *why* you want the expression to be shorter? That is, what problem is solved with having a shorter expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the shortest, but it's shorter than your:

```
l=map(set,[[]]*passwordLen)
```

#### Example

```
>>> l[0].add(1)
>>> print l
[set([1]), set(), set(), set(), set(), set()]
```